# Applying styles to Menu items similar to ContextMenu?

Tags: wpf, xaml, menu, styles

I'm having a little trouble styling the context-menu-like control that drops down when you click on a `MenuItem`. I tried styling `ContextMenu`, but I guess they aren't the same control because it only affected the actual context menu. So I was wondering how I would access the list of MenuItems, like what `TargetType` it is or if I have to access it some other way. I also tried styling `HeaderedContentControl`, which didn't appear to change anything.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to set style on `Menu` control or not? And what exactly do you want to change / add style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to modify the `MenuItem` `ControlTemplate`. There is an example on MSDN that should serve as a good starting point.

[MenuItem ControlTemplate Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I downloaded the template into my App.xaml file, but it throws an exception saying it can't find "WindowBackgroundBrush", even though the brush is there, do you know what could be causing it?

Comment: You need to make sure that your Brushes are declared before your MenuItem ControlTemplate. So if they are in the same file, Brushes above MenuItem ControlTemplate.